# Installing @mui/material results in dependency conflict

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, node-modules, mern

I am trying to install **@mui/material**

> npm install @mui/material

But, when I do it throws this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: paper-kit-react@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.8.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.8.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.10.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!   1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/material@5.10.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/pc/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you are using React Version 16.8.6 .
You need at least React Version >= 17.0.0 as you can read in the MUI docs.
I hope this solves your problem.
[image: MUI installation]